# How to pass input value from popup.html to current page with a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to grab the textarea value of the form from the popup.html file and display it on a test page with the id="demo". But for some reasons I'm not getting anything back.

Here is the error I've got: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Manifest V3

```
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "0.01",
  "description": "-",
 "background":{
   "service_worker": "background.js"
 },
    "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting"],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "web_accessible_resources": [{
  "resources": ["popup.js"],
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
}],
  "manifest_version": 3,
    "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
        <form id="myForm">
            <textarea id="summary" name="summary" rows="6" cols="35">
            </textarea>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Popup.js

```
// Initialize submit
let submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
   
// When the button is clicked, inject setFormInput into current page
submitButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });

  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: setFormInput,
  });
});

// The body of this function will be executed as a content script inside the
// current page
function setFormInput() {

alert('form submitted');

var formTextarea = document.getElementById("summary").value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerText = formTextarea;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see that error in chrome://extensions UI and it's an old error caused by your old incorrect code, it's no longer relevant. Click the `clear all` button there.

Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools and console: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

**The actual problem** is the code you inject in the web page (setFormInput) tries to access elements from the popup page, which is a totally different page.

```js
submitButton.addEventListener('click', async evt => {
  evt.preventDefault(); // prevents `submit` event from reloading the popup
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
  const text = document.getElementById('summary').value;
  await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    func: (id, text) => {
      document.getElementById(id).textContent = text;
    },
    args: ['demo', text],
  });
});
```

P.S. There's no need for `web_accessible_resources` and `host_permissions` for this task.

Comment: Ok it works, many thanks for your time and the explanations.